# Params + Acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still having major issues figuring out why it isn't passing the params. They are in my strong params shown below but no matter what I do it still not passing them.

Really appreciate any feedback on this:

book.rb

```
def upvote

  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @book.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to books_path
end

def downvote
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @book.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to books_path
end
```

params

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :size, :cat, :user_id, :votable, :voter, :vote_scope) 
end
```

The error from the logs:

```
Started PUT "/books/1/like" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 22:13:14 +0000
Processing by BooksController#upvote as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"m+/mqdx3cfcn65TPyTgyzlm2nWCgJ4QY/b6botgrySo=", "book_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Book Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."voter_id" = 1 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL AND "votes"."voter_type" = 'User'  [["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Book"]]
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for ActsAsVotable::Vote: votable, voter, vote_scope
    app/controllers/books_controller.rb:92:in `upvote'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/books
Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

I have acts as votable in my model but it is not saving the like to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie programming and in Rails, but right now I am using acts_as_votable and it works for me.

I never created a method for upvote or downvote on muy voteable model (Answer). I just include the resources on my routes and then created links for it.

For you, it will be like:

```
# routes.rb
  ...
  resources: :books do
    member do
      get :upvote, :downvote, (maybe you also want:), :unvote
    end
  end
  ...
```

With that settled, all you need to vote is:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", upvote_answer_path(@answer) %>
```

Downvote and Unvote are the same, just check **rake routes** and you will find them.

That should achieve your goal avoiding to create new method, which, by the way, I do not know if it a better approach than mine, but mine is working. I would love to read a comment about it from some expert on Rails security (because, in that, sense, creating a method on Book.rb might happen to be better option...).

Good luck.